# Como setar valor de var JS para campo do html?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho o seguinte código que:
Quando um campo entra em focus ele chama uma função para verificar qual campo está em fócus para mudar o valor de uma variável em um tooltip!

Exemplo:

```
    //Aqui quando o campo entra no focus ele chama a função Aalerta passando o nome!
                    <td align="right" >
                        <font face="arial" color="blue" size="-1" disabled="">Nome do Usuário : </font>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left">
                        <input type="text" aonfocus="Aalerta(this.name)" name="tx_nome_usua" onblur="evento(this)" id="nome"  size="15" value="" >
                    </td>
//Essa é a tooltip que no echo do data-title eu quero mudar o valor de $j
<td><span name="tooltip" style="color: blue;" data-title="<?php echo $campo[$j]?>" class="tooltip">?</span></td>
```

No função `Aalert()` eu verifico o nome do campo e quero mudar o valor de **$j**

```
function Aalerta(nome){
    switch(nome){
        case 'tx_nome_usua' :
            var value = 1;
            document.getElementsByName('tooltip')[0].setAttribute("data-title",[+ value]);          
        break;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Assim eu gostaria de saber: "Como setar o **value** que eu determino no case, para ficar no lugar do **$j**!"

Se for seguir o escopo depois de executar o JS' eu queria que ficasse assim no `span do html`:

```
<td><span name="tooltip" style="color: blue;" data-title="<?php echo $campo['1']?>" class="tooltip">?</span></td>
```

Mudando somente o `$j`!

Comment: Alexandre, pode usar bibliotecas como MooTools ou jQuery? Gostava de o apanhar no chat pois há conceitos que acho ainda estão pouco claros entre lado cliente e servidor.

Comment: infelizmente não posso utilizar tais bibliotecas por meios "técnicos" do trabalho!

Comment: Alexandre, podemos concluir que esta resposta ficou esclarecida com o chat? se quiser pode aceitar.

Comment: Sim podemos esclarecer que ficou tudo correto' Obrigado pelo apoio'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro criar um event handler e fazer o *set* com s`this.setAttribute('data-title', texto);` e com o texto do elemento que estiver em foco.

Para saber qual o elemento em foco na página pode usar `document.activeElment`.
Pode criar uma array com o texto de cada nome amigável de cada campo e ir buscar essa string usando o `.name` do elemento ativo/foco.

Algo como:

```
<script>
var tooltipSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
for (var i = 0; i < tooltipSpan.length; i++) {
    tooltipSpan[i].addEventListener('mouseover', fnTitulo, false);
}

function fnTitulo() {
    if (!document.activeElement || document.activeElement == document.body || !document.activeElement.name) return;
    var texto = arrayTexto[document.activeElement.name] || 'Nenhum input focado';
    this.setAttribute('data-title', texto);
}
</script>
```

Pode colocar este script no fundo da página, depois do HTML, ou dentro de uma função que só corre quando o DOM estiver pronto como:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // código aqui
});
```